# Save Form Data in UI Component form Not Working

Tags: magento2

This is My save Button

```
 use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;

 class SaveButton extends GenericButton implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
public function getButtonData()
{
    return [
        'label' => __('Save Contact'),
        'class' => 'save primary',
        'data_attribute' => [
            'mage-init' => ['button' => ['event' => 'save']],
            'form-role' => 'save',
        ],
        //'on_click' => sprintf("location.href= '%s';", $this->getSaveUrl()),
        'sort_order' => 90
    ];
}

public function getSaveUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/save', []) 
;
}
}
```

This is My controller

```
 <?php
 namespace My\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Test;

 class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
 {
protected $resultPageFactory;
protected $saveFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    \My\Module\Model\SaveFactory $saveFactory
)
{
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    $this->saveFactory = $saveFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

    if($data)
    {
        try{
            $id = $data['id'];

            $contact = $this->saveFactory->create()->load($id);

            $data = array_filter($data, function($value) {return $value !== ''; });

            $contact->setData($data);
            $contact->save();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Successfully saved the item.'));
            $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Session')->setFormData(false);
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
        }
        catch(\Exception $d)
        {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
            $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Session')->setFormData($data);
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['id' => $contact->getId()]);
        }
    }

     return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
}
}
```

Comment: Button is not working oR Do not get data at POST COntroller

Comment: when i am pressing "Save Contact" it shows HTTP 500 error

Comment: It means `My\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Test\Save: execute` is hitting but save.php has some syntax issue OR Di compile issue. That why it is showing 500 error

Comment: can you help me to solve this error, i am stuck for the whole day

Comment: let me  check.. the code..

Answer (score 0):

**Try below solution:**

```
<?php

namespace My\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Test;

class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action 
{

    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $saveFactory;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
         \My\Module\Model\SaveFactory $saveFactory   
    ){
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->saveFactory = $saveFactory;
    }


    public function execute() {
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

        if ($data) {
            try {
                $id = $data['id'];

                $contact = $this->saveFactory->create();

                if($this->getRequest()->getParam('id')){
                    $contact->load($id);
                }

                $data = array_filter($data, function($value) {
                    return $value !== '';
                });

                $contact->setData($data);
                $contact->save();
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Successfully saved the item.'));
                $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Session')->setFormData(false);
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            } catch (\Exception $d) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
                $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Session')->setFormData($data);
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['id' => $contact->getId()]);
            }
        }

        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }

}
```

Donot need to add `\Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,`.

> After these changes, Please do Di compile properly.

Comment: still same error